# hudson build a project using junit maven and HSQLDB in server mode

Tags: maven-2, hudson, hsqldb

I have a project of persistence with spring and hibernate built with maven,  I'm running the testing using Junit and a test database **HSQLDB**, when I do a test first initialize the database **HSQLDB** in server mode, is there some way to make hudson initializes the database, or with maven ?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [DbUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) and the [DbUnit Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/dbunit-maven-plugin/) for that. You can use it to [Clear database and insert a dataset before test phase](http://mojo.codehaus.org/dbunit-maven-plugin/examples/clean-insert.html) and/or to setup data for each test cases (see the [Getting Started](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/howto.html) for JUnit 3, see [this blog](http://www.testearly.com/2006/07/23/dbunit-with-junit-4/) post for example for JUnit 4).

Another option would be to use the [SQL Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/). The [examples](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/examples/execute.html) section has a configuration that shows how to drop/create a database and schema, then populate it before the test phase, and drop the database after the test phase).

The later approach gives you less control on data setup between tests which is why I prefer DbUnit.

Comment: I start with SQL Maven Plugin and it works thanks, But next time I will use DbUnit

Comment: From what I read, `DbUnit Maven Plugin` seems to support only DML and not DDL. While `SQL Maven Plugin` supports both DML and DDL - which comes in handy to first create the schema and then init data, both through maven.

Answer (score 1):

I add the folowing to pom.

```
<build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
                <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.0.7</version>
            </extension>
            <extension>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.14</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>

                <configuration>
                    <components>
                        <component>
                            <name>hbm2java</name>
                            <implementation>annotationconfiguration</implementation>
                            <outputDirectory>/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                        </component>

                    </components>
                    <componentProperties>
                        <jdk5>true</jdk5>
                        <export>false</export>
                        <drop>true</drop>
                        <outputfilename>schema.sql</outputfilename>
                    </componentProperties>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-ddl</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <!--Genera Esquema-->
                            <goal>hbm2ddl</goal>
                            <!--Genera Clases -->
                        <!-- <goal>hbm2java</goal>  -->

                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>



            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-schema</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                            <srcFiles>
                                <srcFile>target/hibernate3/sql/schema.sql</srcFile>
                            </srcFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>


                    <execution>
                        <id>drop-db-after-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>execute</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                                <sqlCommand>DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE</sqlCommand>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>

                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                            <version>1.8.0.7</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>

                    <configuration>
                        <driver>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</driver>
                        <username>sa</username>
                        <password></password>
                        <url>jdbc:hsqldb:file:etc/out/test.db;shutdown=true</url>
                        <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                        <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </build>
```

and the folowing to my datasource:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" lazy-init="true"
    destroy-method="close">
 <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />

 <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:etc/out/test.db;shutdown=true" />


    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

We do that with Maven under Hudson, with a profile that triggers the maven-antrun-plugin in the process-test-resources phase. In our case the maven-antrun-plugin runs a Java class that generates the schema, but of course there are other options. It looks like this:

```
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generate-database-schema-new</id>
                            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <tasks>
                                    ...
                                </tasks>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Comment: This strategy also is valid for me